# Sub-query is Not Working for Date_Part()

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I want to pass the subquery as an argument to the `EXTRACT()` function of Postgres to get the number of the day of the week but it is not working.

**Working Code:**

```
SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM DATE '2018-06-07');
It returns:

+-------------+
| date_part   |
|-------------|
| 4.0         |
+-------------+
```

**Not Working Code:**

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE 
   (SELECT start_date from leaves where submitted_by=245 and type_id = 16)
);
It returns
syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE (SELECT submitted_on FROM leave...
```

I don't know why `EXTRACT()` function is not accepting subquery result as the query:

```
SELECT start_date from leaves where submitted_by=245 and type_id = 16;
```

returns the following which I think is identical I have passed as a 
    date string in the working example.

```
+--------------+
| start_date   |
|--------------|
| 2018-06-07   |
+--------------+
```

Can somebody correct it or let me know some other way to get the number of the day of the week.

Comment: The `DATE` keyword is a part of the date literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply it to the column of the select:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW from start_date)
from leaves 
where submitted_by=245 and type_id = 16
```

If you really want to use a scalar sub-query, then you must get rid of the `DATE` keyword, that is only needed to specify date constants.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM 
                 (SELECT start_date from leaves where submitted_by=245 and type_id = 16)
               );
```

Comment: Thanks, @a_hores_with_no_name, I couldn't find it in docs and even couldn't get that I should go without the `DATE` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Put the function *inside* the `select`:

```
select (select extract(dow from start_date)
        from leaves
        where submitted_by = 245 and type_id = 16
       )
```

I don't see the advantage for using a subquery in the `select` for this (as opposed to -- say -- moving the subquery to the `from`.  But this should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon for your help. I have accepted the other answer because of the explaination `you must get rid of the DATE keyword, that is only needed to specify date constants.`